# Angular Google Maps - creating map difference between AGM-MAP tag and using map = new google.maps.Map()

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I created a map with markers on Google Map with Angular using the agm-map and agm-marker tags. It was pretty easy and straightfoward but I just found that you can also create a map by using the 
`map = new google.maps.MAP(document.getElementById("id"))`
and create a marker with new `google.Maps.Marker({position: LatLng, map: map})`. These markers seems to have more options like `setPosition()`, `getPosition()`, `clickable()`, `getvisible()`, etc. 
Do you have all those options with the agm-marker way?
Can you use the google.Maps.Marker and link it to a map made with agm-map tag?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AGM maps is quite helpful and quick if you need to work with simple marker and maps. With more and more complex functions , where drawing and other manipulations are involved, AGM maps might have the feature but not a clear cut example or documentation.

You can choose to directly use Google Maps API without the need to using AGM Maps.

Please find the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@nixonaugustine5/integrating-angular-with-google-maps-advanced-using-google-drawing-manager-e889e0b25d2a) and [here](https://medium.com/@nixonaugustine5/angular-google-maps-integration-advanced-using-google-drawing-manager-8a6eac6540e1).